# Way to disable launcher-popups without installing new software?

Tags: unity, launcher

I'd like to disable the pop-up that appears when I move my mouse over a Launcher-Icon. The popups always cover up stuff I'm trying to look at.

In this screenshot, I want to disable the popup that says "Firefox Web Browser":

[image]

Comment: Can anything be done to get more attention for this question in the hopes of getting it answered?